# How can I reformat date using Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, foreach, openweathermap

I'm using openweather 3hours forecast api. Why does the date show only the same time? even though values are different? date is supposed to be every three hours. I formatted the date in weatherItem.dart after iterating over each item.. how can I get the date with every three hours and render on the screen?

Comment: The first thing I would recommend you do is to lose the <String, dynamic> type parameters and just have the `Map` type stand on its own. I've had issues with Dart on multiple occasions because of this.

Comment: Also, I can't find your WeatherData class and what its toString method looks like

Comment: I have added the weatherData class.. I implemented toString method so that output can get printed out, I got instance of class name as an output without toString method..

Comment: What's the reason for lowing the <String, dynamic> type parameters?

Comment: I don't really know. All I know is that when I annotate the Map object returned by jsonDecode with some type parameters, I get errors and crashes

Comment: You were wondering why the date looks like that. Apparently, that's how the API returns its dates. You can try to parse it using DateTime.parse, or you parse it yourself, it's not that hard. EDIT: Just found that you already parsed the date with DateTime. DateTime formatted the result like that

Comment: You're setting the text color to white in weatherItem. Maybe that's the problem? If you're on dark mode, that shouldn't be an issue buh if not...

Comment: That was the problem.. I set the text color white in weatherItem..how can I miss this!?! thank you so much.. you really helped me a lot.. I now see the format is not what I want..I have updated the post. I'm using openweather 3hours forecast api..how can I change the format from 01-03-2022 to 01-03-2022 with time for every three hours?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JSON data you provided with the `dt_txt` key, you'll find that the date format does not contain time. So the JSON data you're getting does not contain a valid time you can use